# in JSLint, why is this block empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I'm struggleing a bit with JSLint. I have the following code:

```
// inside a for-loop
if ( aMatch.length > 0 ){
    temp =  wrap.find( aMatch );                                
    break;
} else if ( aMatch.length === 0 && o.siteMap[targetPath].length !== 0 ){
    temp = targetPath;
    break;
}
```

JSLint complains:

```
Empty block   "if ( aMatch.length > 0 ){"
```

**Question:**
What is the problem with the snippet. The "block" is not empty to me...

Thanks for some insights!

**EDIT**:
This is the whole function in questions (sans comments)

```
loopHistory: function (scope, setPageContainer) {

    var self = this,
        o = self.options,
        wrap = $('div:jqmData(wrapper="true")').length > 1 ? $('div:jqmData(wrapper="true")').last() : $('div:jqmData(wrapper="true")'),
        $loopLength = $.mobile.urlHistory.stack.length-1, 
        temp, aMatch, parsedPath, dUrl, targetPath, i;

    if ( scope === "internal") {
        if ( $loopLength >= 2) {

            for ( i = $loopLength; i>1; i--) {
                parsedPath = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( $.mobile.urlHistory.stack[i-1].url );      
                targetPath = parsedPath.search.length !== "" ? ( parsedPath.pathname + parsedPath.search ) : parsedPath.pathname;

            if ( setPageContainer.jqmData('id') === $.mobile.urlHistory.stack[i-1].pageContainer.jqmData('id') && targetPath !== $.mobile.path.parseUrl( $.mobile.urlHistory.stack[$.mobile.urlHistory.activeIndex].pageUrl ).pathname ) {

                aMatch = $('div.ui-page').filter(function(){ return $(this).jqmData('url') === targetPath; });

                if ( aMatch.length === 0 && o.siteMap[targetPath].length !== 0 ){

                }

                ... ahh yes.... 
                if ( aMatch.length > 0 ){
                    temp =  wrap.find( aMatch );                                
                    break;
```

ok. I see...

Comment: Tried your code here http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php . Works just fine. Can you give more details ?

Comment: FWIW: I can't speak for jslint, but jshint doesn't have a problem with that. I put [this code](http://pastie.org/5180336) into http://jshint.com and it doesn't complain about any empty blocks (and the empty blocks option is on).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I'm about 75% through my script with JSlint, so I'm trying to get through all the way :-)

Comment: Yep fine on my end as well with JSLint.

Comment: Found it... it was the if-statement before that... Thx for chipping in...

Comment: Don't forget to answer your own question. Others may stumble on this question and would be glad to see it.

Comment: Done. Might as well close, too.

Answer (score 6):

Ok. My bad. There was an empty if-else block right before the block mentioned by JSLint.

```
if ( aMatch.length === 0 && o.siteMap[targetPath].length !== 0 ){  }


if ( aMatch.length > 0 ){
   temp =  wrap.find( aMatch );                                
   break;
```

Never noticed.